# Oracle driver for old VB application

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, postgresql

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your answers.
I'm a java programmeram and I m trying to migrate an old application VB (framework 1.0 I think) from a Postgres database to an oracle database.

I think (I hope) the problem should be reduced to change a connection string and a driver somewhere..
To connect to the db application uses ADOB / ADOX and I do not think (but I could be wrong) that it is used ODBC.

To connect to Postgres application used  the libpq.dll and pgOleDB.dll libraries and this connection string in a configuration file 
strConnDb= Provider=postgresql.pgole; Password=xx; User ID=xxx; Data Source=10.192.4.48; Location=DB_JUST_R; Extended Properties=;

Finally my question is  where can I download the "provider" for Oracle and what should I write in the connection string? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In best case you just have to change the connection string to

```
strConnDb = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source={database TNS alias};Password=xxxx;User ID=xxx"
```

You can download "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" driver from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)